# Xcode 9 not refreshing provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am getting the `Failed to create provisioning profile.` and `No profiles for ... were found` AFTER I create my app id and push notification certificate. If I were to change the bundle id to something else it works fine, but they need to be the same. When I go to delete existing profiles, this is all I get,[image]When I click manage certificates nothing shows up, and when I click download all profiles nothing changes. I tried restarting xcode. Removing the account and adding it. Not sure what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Xcode 9 is still in beta. Have you tried with Xcode 8?

Comment: Yup, same issue

Comment: Are you using Xcode automatic code signing? It won't create any profiles until you try to either try to run on a physical device, or build the app for distribution.  Since you said it works if you change the bundle ID, my guess is that the app bundle Id you are trying to build with is owned by another Apple developer account, so Apple's dev site won't allow you to create a provisioning profile for an app ID you don't "own".